# How to partially color a line in WPF C#(From Code Behind)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

Line A to B is the initial line (filled in black). I'm drawing it using

```
Rectangle = System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
```

I need to partially color the same line from point A1 to B in red (as shown).

How could I achieve it from code behind?

Note: I do not have the luxury of recreating (redrawing) the line here. I only need to partially color the already existing line and based on some other condition and I may need to revert it back to black.

Comment: You could use a LinearGradientBrush with a very steep gradient at A1, draw a second rectangle, write a control that supports such a feature, etc. What are you using it for and what have you tried so far? What's the surrounding context?

Comment: Any code to show? [ask]

Comment: @iYaday Since this point A1 seems to be not fixed at 50% or so, is this some kind of progress bar, gauge or something?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I am trying to create a tree and it's branches using line. I have to color a branch from root to the top. Initially tree and it's branches will be black, now i only need to color an already existing branch from bottom to half way to top(Some Y-Axis value) with red and the remaining half should remain black.

Comment: @iYadav I see. Regarding your last comment on Pranay's answer: Do you have direct access to the control by name (e.g. `rect1.Fill = Brushes.Black`)? How would you currently change the color of the entire line - can you do that? (I'm asking because the approach I'm preparing wouldn't be much help otherwise)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Spot on. I am currently doing rect1.Fill = Brushes.Black and it's changing entire line color. That is fine. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: @iYadav No that should be sufficient information, I should have something usable in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a simple two-colored gradient, you need to add two Gradient-Stops at the same position to make sure the color doesn't just slowly fade from one into the other. The below helper class demonstrates how that would work:

```
public static class GradientGenerator
{
    public static Brush GenerateTwoColorBrush(Color color1, Color color2, double ratio)
    {
        GradientStopCollection collection = new GradientStopCollection();

        collection.Add(new GradientStop(color1, 0));
        collection.Add(new GradientStop(color1, ratio));
        collection.Add(new GradientStop(color2, ratio));
        collection.Add(new GradientStop(color2, 1.0));

        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(collection);
        return brush;
    }
}
```

In your code-behind you can simply call the generator's method to get a gradient of your two colors at a specified ratio (`0.0` - `1.0`):

```
rectBlack.Fill = GenerateTwoColorBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.Red, 0.5);
```

Should you ever need horizontal or sloped gradients instead, simply set the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` properties of the `LinearGradientBrush`.

Expected outcome:

[image: How it would / should look]

---

Should you ever decide to take a more MVVM-ish approach, or create your tree in XAML, you can simply use this method with an `IValueConverter` to update the Brush automatically.

```
public class RatioToGradientConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Color Color1 { get; set; }
    public Color Color2 { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double ratio = 0;
        if (value is double)
            ratio = (double) value;

        return GradientGenerator.GenerateTwoColorBrush(Color1, Color2, ratio);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

The example above for example was made this way:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:RatioToGradientConverter Color1="Black" Color2="Red" x:Key="gradientConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Rectangle Width="10" Height="200" Name="rect1"
               Fill="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource gradientConverter}}" />
    <Slider Height="200" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Name="slider"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Now i just need to tweak a bit to suit my requirement. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that thing with the help of `LinearGradientBrush` i.e. defining brush in your resource and use it.

[Tip: How to use a LinearGradientBrush](https://web.archive.org/web/20100613212751/http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/Tip-How-to-use-a-LinearGradientBrush.aspx)

Below is example code form MSDN , that is for Rectangle but you can use same brush coding for line.

```
Rectangle diagonalFillRectangle = new Rectangle();
diagonalFillRectangle.Width = 200;
diagonalFillRectangle.Height = 100;

// Create a diagonal linear gradient with four stops.   
LinearGradientBrush myLinearGradientBrush =
    new LinearGradientBrush();
myLinearGradientBrush.StartPoint = new Point(0,0);
myLinearGradientBrush.EndPoint = new Point(1,1);
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
    new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
    new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.25));                
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
    new GradientStop(Colors.Blue, 0.75));        
myLinearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
    new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 1.0));

// Use the brush to paint the rectangle.
diagonalFillRectangle.Fill = myLinearGradientBrush;
```

[Painting with Solid Colors and Gradients Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/painting-with-solid-colors-and-gradients-overview)

Comment: @MickyD - what if the answer is just one word ....here is just use LinearGradientBrush

Comment: That would hardly be an answer (which is why I put exactly that in a comment instead of an answer).

Comment: Links can break.  A five word answer isn't particularly informative

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer -dont get me wrong but its better to put it as answer , right because you answer might help others , comment most of the people igonore

Comment: @MickyD - thats y i provided sample code ...

Comment: That's why I usually ask what the intended purpose is and what they have tried before answering questions :)

Comment: @PranayRana that's why  I deleted my original comment and upvoted you :)

Comment: @MickyD - thank you for that ....by the time you comment get deleted same time i inserted my comment and update also ...sorry for tha t

Comment: No harm done good sir :)

Comment: As suggested by @ManfredRadlwimmer I have edited by question with more specific requirement.

Comment: @iYadav- you just need to use normal brush to make it back again ...it just based on you if & else condition

Comment: @PranayRana As i have mentioned, i am not recreating/redrawing the line again in black, i only have to color the existing line partially to red/black dynamically from code behind.

Comment: @iYadav - yes you can do that when you create line than you have object of line that you can color...same in agobe code rectangle is object that used for coloring ...if i want to change color of that than same object i have to use with diffrent color no need to redraw

Comment: @PranayRana Then it would color the entire line. Eg: rect1.Fill = Brushes.Black; changed to rect1.Fill = Brushes.Red would change the entire line from Black to Red(i.e From Point A to Point B). What i need here is Partial coloring. From Point A to A1 should remain in black but Point A1 to Point B in red without redrawing the line.

Comment: @iYadav - buddy rather than  rect1.Fill = Brushes.Red you have to use linearbush to fill you like this linearbrush consist of ( black and red ) color ...that is my answer ... if you want to change back to full black than use rect1.Fill = Brushes.Black; thats it ...i hop you got not ...use linearbrush to color line with half black & half red...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the following idea as well:

Split the Rectangle in two parts, that means in the end you draw a recangle from A to A1 with black color and the second one from A1 to B in red color.

Comment: That's the problem here, i do not have the luxury of recreating(redrawing) the line here. I only need to partially color the already existing line and based on some condition, i may need to revert it back to black color.

Comment: @iYadav That an important piece of information. You should include that in your original question, along with other restrictions and requirements.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Appreciate your suggestion. I have edited my question.